# Windows 7 Bootable Install USB doesn't get past Starting Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb

I'm trying to reinstall Windows, but after I boot off of the USB drive with the bootable image, I can't get past "Starting Windows" with the logo. I have checked the Sums of the iso I downloaded and they are correct, and I used the official Windows 7 DVD/USB creator tool. I have tried using a USB stick and a DVD, but the result is the same.

Toshiba L850

Intel i3-2370M

Edit: I believe the issue may lie with my BIOS not having been set to Compatibility mode (IDE). Apparently it was getting stuck at CLASSPNP.SYS and there is plenty of support for that issue. I have changed the setting and will now attempt again.

It didn't work. I tried booting with a log, and it crashed, but here is the log
http://pastebin.com/XAawbqcS

Comment: Does the ISO boot if you burn it to DVD? To rule out the ISO.

Comment: Yes. As in, whether I use a USB drive or a DVD, I can boot off of the device, it'll give me the "Windows is loading files" bar, then the "Starting WIndows" with the logo where it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling and make sure that the first item in the boot order is the USB drive and the second item is your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 possible reasons:

1. Potentially the image itself can be faulty. The only way is to test it on the other hardware.
2. Drivers in the image or some hardware in your configuration is preventing to start Windows.
3. Possible issue with the hard drive. Windows is not able to read configuration data.

Hence, you need to test this image on another hardware; try to disable all external and non-obligatory connected devices; try to start Windows in safe mode. If it starts in safe mode - the issue seems to be with drivers.

Comment: If the image was faulty, then the SHA1 and MD5 sums wouldn't check out, right?

Might be the hardware.

I doubt it's the HDD, as I'm booting off of the DVD/USB and both have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to run windows 7 aka install it on a usb drive and run from same  as in a os on key setup? if so  it will always fail at the windows logo on boot  as windows 7 does not support disk on key  or what is known as a system on the move windows 8.1 and 10 however do support the  option of running windows from a thumb drive.

Comment: I have Win7 installed on my HDD but want to reinstall it. When I tried to boot off of the USB to install, it got stuck. after that, the HDD install didn't work anymore either. So in short, no

Comment: you may  actually need to replace your hdd  i had a situation exactly like this  and it ended up being the hdd had actually taken a crap on me during the reinstall and i spent get this, 3 days trying to install  windows before i broke down and tried a new drive. it worked perfectly  on a new drive so i tested the other one and  yep it was a turd.

Comment: I'm running a CHKDSK on the HDD using my brothers computer and a USB-SATA cable right now, but it's very slow.